# mysql_connect connection lifetime

Tags: php, mysql, connection, lifetime

What happes when the script that made `@mysql_connect($server, $user, $password)` dies?
How long does it live?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Connections opened by mysql_connect()
>   are closed at script exit, unless
>   closed earlier by calls to
>   mysql_close().

http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn41re774.html

Comment: Is there any other source that says it?

Comment: the php manual itself says so. see the notes section at: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

It will close when your script ends, but it's better practice to close it explicitly using `mysql_close()` - releasing the link when you don't need it.